# Probability of minimum order stats in case of discrete distribution (Poisson)

Tags: probability, order-statistics

$X_1$,$X_2$ ~ $P(1)$, $Y$ = Min{$X_1$,$X_2$} $\mathbb\quad P(Y=1)$ =$?$

I tried this in two different ways and I am getting a different answer in both:-

1. Firstly I made PDF of $X_{(1)}$ = $n(1-F(x))^{n-1}f(x)$ = $$\frac{2e^{-1}}{x!}(1-\sum_{x=0}^x \frac{e^{-1}}{x!}) $$ Then after Putting the value $\mathbb1$, I get, $$\frac{2e-4}{e^2}$$
2. $\mathbb\quad P(Y=1)$ = $\mathbb\quad P(X_1=1)P(X_2>=1)+P(X_2=1)P(X_1>=1)-P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1)$ = $$\frac{2e-3}{e^2}$$
   Second answer is correct but I don't understand what I have done wrong in first part. Is it that this PDF of order stats is good in continuous cases as what I think the PDF didn't include the case when both $X_1$,$X_2$ are equal to 1. Kindly help.

Comment: What is $f(x)$? There is no pdf for a  discrete distribution.

Comment: X follows Poisson with mean 1. I have taken PMF of poisson distribution.

Comment: To get $n(1-F(x))^{n-1}f(x)$ you have taken a derivative of $(1-F(x))^{n}$.  But you cannot do that with a discrete distribution.  Instead you want the difference $(1-F(x-1))^{n}-(1-F(x))^{n}$

Comment: ohhh yaaa thnku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula in the first part is wrong.

$P(X_{(1)}\leq x)=1-P(X_1>x)^{2}=1-(1-F(x))^{2}$. So $P(X_{(1)}= 1)=(1-F(0))^{2}-(1-F(1))^{2}=(1-e^{-1})^{2}-(1-2e^{-1})^{2}=\frac {2e-3}{e^{2}}$.